# NFePHP 3.10 - XML passa em 3 validadores mas NÃO transmite para Sefaz

Tags: php, nfe

Estou usando a API do NfePHP. O objetivo é bem simples. Recebe um TXT gerado nos padrões do Emissor da Sefaz. Faz a transformação em XML e transmite.
Eu valido o XML nestes validadores, sem problemas:

- http://www.semx.com.br
- https://www.sefaz.rs.gov.br/nfe/NFE-VAL.aspx

Mas no API dá o seguinte retorno erro 225:

> “Rejeição: Falha no Schema XML do lote de Nfe”

Já li toneladas de coisas na internet e não consegui achar uma solução.

Alguém ai teria como me ajudar?
Tem como saber mais detalhes do erro, além dessa mensagem?

Answer (score 0):

A Rejeição (225): “Falha no Schema XML do lote de NFe (Nota Fiscal Eletrônica) ” indica que o preenchimento da NF-e pode ter sido feito de forma errada, porém, como essa rejeição é genérica, temos que considerar outros problemas como:

```
Espaços entre as TAGs do XML;
Quebras de Linhas;
Caracteres especiais;
Nome de TAGs errados;
Versão do XML diferente do esperado pelo Web Service;
```

Na prática, o que isso significa?

A má formação do arquivo XML vai influenciar na validação dos schemas da NF-e e resultará na rejeição 225.

Caso de exemplo:

Caso tenha feito uma NF-e que contenha espaços entre as tags, quebras de linha ou ainda tenha informado nomes de tags errados, a rejeição 225 será aplicada.